# How to group multiple Views without using nested Layouts

Tags: android, android-layout

Consider this situation:

```
<LinearLayout style="@style/Basic_W_mp_H_wc_Vertical">

    <!-- IMAGE-1 -->
    <TextView style="@style/Copyright_TextView_1" />
    <ImageView style="@style/Copyright_Image_1" />
    <include layout="@layout/layout_copyright_info"/>
    <View style="@style/HorizontalSeparatorGray"/>

    <!-- IMAGE-2 -->    
    <TextView style="@style/Copyright_TextView_2" />
    <ImageView style="@style/Copyright_Image_2" />
    <include layout="@layout/layout_copyright_info"/>
    <View style="@style/HorizontalSeparatorGray"/>

    <!-- IMAGE-X -->
    [...]
</LinearLayout>
```

Now I want to hide copyright information for `IMAGE-1`. I have two options:

1. Create a *wrap-layout* (`LinearLayout`) with an `Id`, so I can find and hide it
2. Give `Id` for *every* View find and hide them.

The first option will work, but I don't want to create an extra [nested layout](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/optimizing-layout.html#Revise) for this.
The second option will also work, but my layout will get unreadable if every view has an Id.

I know there is a third *memory-optimized* option to group multiple views, but I can't remember how it works and google search gives me always ViewGroup...

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

You could try to use what's called the [merge](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html#Merge) tag and pair it with the [include](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html#Merge) tag. What this does is it will allow you to use the same layouts in different files (since you seem to have multiple groups together).  The `<merge/>` tag will merge the elements in to the top-level layout (in this case a LinearLayout). I have not used it with this scenario, so I imagine what will happen is you will not be able to retrieve them in a group. It is worth a shot though.

I think option 1 is not a bad choice either for these reasons:

1. It's easier to code. If you don't group them together than you'll have an extra lines and remember extra IDs.  With just one Layout wrapped around it, then you can just hide one layout.
2. It's easier to maintain. What happens if you change the copyright look? What happens if you want to change the rest of the layout?  With one wrapped, it's easier to just fiddle around with one view and everything inside stays intact.
3. The performance hit isn't *that* bad.  Overall, this looks like the top-most root view. Inflating this Layout won't be as bad as if you were say, inflating a ListView item.  This is a one-and-done operation and that's it. You don't want to fall in to the trap of doing [premature optimization](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil) where you sacrifice code maintainability in favor of optimizations without any benefit.